# How can I fix this infinite loop caused by my function in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I've seemed to create a bank account log in system that works correctly. The only problem is that once a login is successful, the program would get stuck in a loop. For example: Say, I create my account and set my username as "Hello" and my password as "123".

The program will except these log in details but when I later try to log in with them, the infinite loop would happen.

I've tried amending this problem by plugging in return/global values for status and even put them in as many places in my program as possible but the infinite loop problem still persists. Could you please help me find why the loop keeps executing?

```
users = {}
status = ""

                            #--------------- Login menu -----------------#
def displayMenu():
    global status

    status = input("Are you a registered user? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No \nQ - Quit \n")  
    if status == '1':
        oldUser()
    elif status == '2':
        newUser()
    return status


def mainMenu():
    print("Hello account holder", login,"what service would  you like to use today?")

                            #---------- Screen for new users -------------#

def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users: # check if login name exists
        print ("\nLogin name already exists!\n")
    else:
        createPassw = input("Create password: ")
        users[createLogin] = createPassw # add login and password
        print("\nAccount created!\n")     

                            #---------- Screen for old users -------------#

def oldUser():
    global login

    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    # check if user exists and login matches password
    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
        mainMenu()

    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")



# Main -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


while status != "q":
    status = displayMenu()
```

Comment: Please move your code into a code-block in your question, rather than a .png file. This helps people help you by allowing them to copy your code to test themselves.

Comment: Put the code in your post.  Please don't post an image of it.

Comment: You need to be precise about "the infinite loop would happen".  Do you see a traceback, does the machine freeze, does it not exit the way you expect?  The current code seems to only have one possible infinite loop, which is `while status...`.  The other functions do not have any possibility of recursion: `displayMenu -> oldUser -> mainMenu`, `displayMenu -> newUser`, `displayMenu`, unless you have rewritten `input` or `print`.

Comment: It looks like your final "while" loop after # Main will always execute, because status is never 'q' unless the user types 'q' to quit. Try using another variable to handle the menu or quit actions?

Comment: I fixed the problem. Basically I've removed the final while loop under main and just put displayMenu() so it will only runs once. Then In the functions, I then linked newUser to mainMenu() and oldUser() to mainMenu(). I hope that made sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working exactly as it is designed.

The main loop starts:

```
while status != "q":
    status = displayMenu()
```

Note that your program will only ever "quit" if the user gives an input of `"q"` in the `displayMenu()`, rather than `"Q"`. This can be fixed by checking `status.lower()` instead.

Then you specify that no, you are not a registered user by providing `2` as an input to the `displayMenu()`.

This brings you to `newUser()`, where you create your new account.

You'll then get returned to `displayMenu()`, where you can this time select `1` to login as a registered user, bringing you to `oldUser()`.

Once you enter your login credentials in `oldUser()`, you'll get brought to `mainMenu()`, where it will print the welcome message in `mainMenu()`, then return to `oldUser()`, then to `displayMenu()`, then back to the main loop.

Unless you're expecting something else to happen in `mainMenu()`, the only error here is that you're not normalizing the case of `status` before checking if it is `"q"`.

Comment: The last part of the program was the problem - I just had to put displayMenu() for it to run once to work. All I needed to do was link each function to mainMenu() so the welcome message would show after the user has made an account. Your explanation cleared everything up for me :) thank you

Comment: @MorganMatthews-Read Welcome to SO. Since you've solved your problem, please consider either closing your question or accepting an answer so that the question doesn't show up as "Unanswered".